# Alternate way to access AngularJS isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS isolated scope is a good way to create re-usable components in angular directives. I'm liking it so much. Sometimes it is needed to access child scopes to manipulate data or call methods. To do this angular gives us two options,

(1) Using isolated scope with attribute bindings. like

```
scope: {
    someObject: '='
},
```

(2) From DOM element's scope().$$childHead. Angular official doc doesn't guaranteed that $$childHead will provide the actual child scope. Sometimes it worked, sometimes not.

```
scope().$$childHead
```

The problem of first option is it gives us the option to work with only the binded object/data, not gives us the full access of scope. Maybe it's what Angular wanted to do, but I wanted to get full access of isolated scope together with it's isolated feature. In order to do that I have created the following piece of code (in directive link function I used **new LinkControl(function(scope, element, attr)){...}**):

```
function LinkController(callback){
    var self = this;
    self.callback = callback;

    return function(scope, element, attr){
        LinkController._retainScope(scope, element, attr);
        self.callback.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

LinkController._scopes = {};

LinkController.get = function(scopeId) {
    return LinkController._scopes[scopeId];
};

LinkController._retainScope = function(scope, element, attr){
    if (typeof(attr) === 'undefined') return;
    if (typeof(attr.scopeId) === 'undefined') return;

    var scopeId = attr.scopeId;
    LinkController._scopes[scopeId] = {
        scope: scope,
        element: element,
        attr: attr
    };

    if (typeof(element) != 'undefined') {
        element.on('$destroy', function(){ LinkController._releaseScope(scopeId); });
    }
};

LinkController._releaseScope = function(scopeId){
    delete LinkController._scopes[scopeId];
};
```

**Usages:**

**Parent Controller**

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    var parentData = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    var anotherValue1 = LinkController.get('td01').attr.anotherValue || 'default value';
    var anotherValue3 = LinkController.get('td03').attr.anotherValue || 'default value';

    LinkController.get('td01').scope.data = parentData;
    LinkController.get('td02').scope.showNext();
    LinkController.get('td03').element.css({opacity: '.5'});
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<test-directive scope-id="td01" any-attr="hello world" />
<test-directive scope-id="td02" any-attr="foo bar" />
<test-directive scope-id="td03" any-attr="alibaba" another-value="test value" />
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('testDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: '/url/to/file.html',
        link: new LinkController(function(scope, element, attr){
            scope.data = {};
            scope.showNext = function(){};
            scope.showPrevious = function(){};
        })
    };
});
```

It is memory safe because it is properly releasing the pointer of scopes.

Please let me know your honest opinion, or suggest better way to do this.

Comment: what is it you're trying to do? What isn't working?

Comment: Nothing is wrong except the following: 1. I'm new to AngularJS and 2. I want the full access of isolated scope. That's why I'm using that class LinkController. Just need to know whether I'm I moving to wrong direction or not.

Comment: concept makes no sense whatsoever. Using things like `scope().$$childHead` is highly unusual`. There seems to be something missing in your fundamental understanding of how angular works

Comment: What is the point in calling it "isolated" scope if it is not at all "isolated"? Either you maintain an isolated scope for the directive or you do not but inherit fromparent. There is nothing in between. Refer this great page about [Understanding Scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Comment: Thanks for those resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the point of an **isolated** scope is to keep the scope separate from everything else, separating concerns. You should really interface your directive by providing objects bound to a controller, or via the event system. In other words, your controller should not know anything explicit about your directive internals.

I cannot think of a good reason you would need access to the entire directive scope from a controller.

Comment: Because I want to write less code, eliminate the bindings between parent and child. Lets then think it as 4th type of directive scope that has the option of isolated scope with a public getter.

Comment: I suggest writing a new question outlining what you are trying to achieve by making the scope accessible. I am sure there is a nice concise way to get the result you want, while sticking to modular principles.

Comment: @ Matt I understand your point. The solution of mine is working just fine. But I posted that here in order to catch the eyes of great Angular experts, like you. Based on your comments here I will probably remove my way of solution and start using standard angular way :)